# Android - Overflow widget likes ActionBar

Tags: android, widget, overflow, android-actionbar

I want to create my own action bar that contains list of buttons (icon with text). This has overflow features:
   - whenever the number buttons is too much (or width exceeds the screen size because of long text for example) then this action bar must be overflow. The sample is the weather application of HTC phone as folowing:        
       [image: overflow action bar]

and: 
     [image]

we can flip the buttons in the action bar to do specified actions.

Android already introduces the ActionBar and it has overflow features. However this is not suited for our expectation so I want to create my own widget.

Has anyone has idea how to implement it? 
Thanks.

Comment: Your requirements, or reasons for not being able to use the standard ActionBar (or ActionBarSherlock), aren't very clear to me. Furthermore, the UI element you've pictured from HTC's alarm application just looks like a simple layout composed from standard layout classes. ActionBar / ActionBarSherlock provides an overflow menu. You can also dynamically add / remove action items from it. If the API ActionBar really doesn't suit your needs for some reason, just build something that suits you using normal layout classes like `LinearLayout`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [**`HorizontalScrollView`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html), and put all your stuff in it. By setting the layout width to `match_parent` and layout height to `wrap_content`, you could achieve pretty much the same.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Put the buttons here -->
</HorizontalScrollView>
```